# How to get the custom post data using post id in WordPress?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, theme-development

I am using WordPress, I have to get the custom post type data using post id and I tried the below code but I am getting the error

> WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
> right syntax to use near '* FROM WHERE 1=1 AND .ID = 972 AND
> .post_type = 'test' AND ((.post_s...' at line 1]

I am getting query and array output below.

```
 Array ( [p] => 972 [post_type] => test [post_status] => publish [order] => DESC ) SELECT .* FROM WHERE 1=1 AND .ID = 972 AND .post_type = 'test' AND ((.post_status = 'publish')) ORDER BY .post_date DESC
```

I am using the below code

```
 function postData($wpdb, $parentsdata){
        $args = array(
                      'p' => $parentsdata['utm_id'],
                      'post_type' => 'test',    
                      'post_status' => 'publish',
                      'order'      => 'DESC'
    );
    
      $related = new WP_Query($args);
      print_r($args); // checking parameters
      echo $wpdb->last_query; // query
         
         //$my_post = get_post($parentsdata['utm_id']);
        //echo $my_post->post_title;
    
         wp_reset_query();
     }
```

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with the code you’ve included but seem to have code somewhere that filters the SQL for queries which has broken WP_Query.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I am not getting the wp_posts table name in the sql query.

Comment: Is that `$wpdb` as in `function postData($wpdb,` the same WordPress database object that normally be accessed using `global $wpdb;` (from a function)? And try `echo $related->request;` - what's the output? Also, if you just wanted to get the post data by the ID, you could simply do `get_post( $parentsdata['utm_id'] )` ..

Comment: @SallyCJ, I tried get_post. I am getting the same error.  WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ID = 972 LIMIT 1' at line 1]
SELECT * FROM WHERE ID = 972 LIMIT 1

Comment: If I add table name(wp_posts) in the SQL query and run it in the PHPMyAdmin then it's working.

Comment: @SallyCJ, I already deactivated all the plugins.

Comment: @SallyCJ, Do I need to check-in function.php? My other codes are working. I mean other custom post data .